# Python - dynamic filter for list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter, list-comprehension

I want to write a method that would filter given list of objects depending on what operator or maybe function was provided to filter by.

Now my method looks like this:

```
def filter_by_names(objects, names, exclude=False):
    if exclude:
        return [obj for obj in objects if obj.name not in names]
    else:
        return [obj for obj in objects if obj.name in names]
```

Now it has two filter options, to return objects if its name is in provided names list or to do opposite: return objects whose name is not in provided names list.

What I want is to be able to dynamically specify how to filter. I though using `operator` library, but it seems there is no `not in` operator, so I would need to combine `in` with `not` which is a bit clunky.

I was thinking of using lambda like:

```
def filter_by_names(objects, names, fun=lambda obj, names: obj.name in names):
    return [obj for obj in objects if fun(obj, names)]
```

This one works, but I was wondering maybe there is some better way to do something like that? With lambda I would always need to specify whole function even if I just only need different operator.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want.  The lambda function *is* the operator, no?  Or do you mean "not in " replacing "in"?  Yes, you can parametrize that, but it's likely more trouble than you want.  How general do you want that function?  What range of control do you need?

Comment: @Prune to have control of operator would be good (like `in` `not in` etc). With lambda, it is probably to generic, cause I might not need that much of control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using the [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator, for example

```
>>> n = range(0,11,2)
>>> n
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> exclude = True
>>> [ x for x in range(10) if (x in n) ^ exclude ] # only the one that are not in n
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> exclude = False
>>> [ x for x in range(10) if (x in n) ^ exclude ] # only the one that are also in n
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>>
```

this work because the xor of equals result in false and the xor of different result in true

Comment: and you can take this a step further and filter by any attribute by using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr), or by using a key function like the one from [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) to extract whatever you desire from the object

Comment: As a matter of fact I implemented just that:)

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter_by_names(objects, names, exclude=False):
    return [obj for obj in objects if (obj.name in names) == (not exclude)]
```

Writing that with `not exclude` (rather than `(obj.name not in names) == exclude)`) allows you to pass an arbitrary truthy/falsy value for 'exclude', not just True or False.

Comment: is this the same as the slightly more concise `[obj for obj in objects if (obj.name in names) != exclude]`? Not sure if `not` does some evaluation that `!=` doesn't do

Comment: That would only work if `exclude` was a proper boolean value (`True` or `False`).  `not` is the simplest way to force such a result.

Comment: Riiight, so passing in an empty list `[]` as a stand in for `False` would still work with `== (not exclude)`?

Answer (score 0):

Start with Python [operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).  `contains` and `not` should be enough to give you the desired control.  However, this will be barely shorter than your current code, and the result is harder to read.  On the other hand, this should give you plenty of lovely ideas on what you want to configure next.

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm going with this approach. It is kind of limited, but it does what I currently need.

```
def filter_by_names(objects, names, exclude=False):

    def _filter(names, name):
        if exclude:
            return name not in names
        return name in names

    return [obj for obj in objects if _filter(names, obj.name)]
```

P.S. I dropped `operator` library, because using function which is limited either way, there is no need to have `operator` lib.